# WPF: is it possible to render a circle using GeometryDrawing?

Tags: wpf, geometry, drawing

I've got a GeometryDrawing similar like this:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type wpfhlp:FokusGroupBox},ResourceId=IconTest}">
  <DrawingImage.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup>
      <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="M0,260 L0,600 L110,670 L110,500 L190,550 L190,710 L300,775 L300,430 L150,175"/>
    </DrawingGroup>
  </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

Now I'd like to draw a circle instead, but I only can find commands to move, draw a line, nothing to draw a circle.

Is there some way to get the GeometryDrawing to draw a circle?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
....
<GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="0,0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
</GeometryDrawing>
```

Alternatively, you can also use [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax) to draw two elliptic arcs (upper and lower half of the circle):

```
<GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="M -1,0 A 1,1 0 1 1 1,0 M -1,0 A 1,1 0 1 0 1,0" />
```

In case you're wondering, this is what those cryptic drawing instructions mean:

- `M -1,0`: Start drawing at point (-1, 0).
- `A 1,1 0 1 1 1,0`: Draw an elliptic arc with radius (1, 1) to point (1, 0). The single-digit flags in between mean: no rotation (0), angle 180° or larger (1), positive-angle direction (1, meaning [clockwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.sweepdirection?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)). This yields the upper half of the circle.
- `M -1,0`: Start drawing again at point (-1, 0)
- `A 1,1 0 1 0 1,0`: Draw the same arc as before, only this time in negative-angle direction (0, meaning counter-clockwise).

Answer (score 13):

```
<Path Stretch="Fill" 
      Fill="Transparent" 
      Stroke="Black" 
      StrokeThickness="5" 
      Data="M 0,0 A 180,180 180 1 1 1,1 Z"/>
```

Comment: Note that this is not a full circle. There is a small gap between the start point (0,0) and the end point (1,1) which is closed by a straight line by the `Z` command. For a full circle you need to draw at least two segments, e.g. two semicircles. Besides that, the rotation about 180 degrees (of a circle!) is plain nonsense.

Comment: This answer is horrible, regarding the fact that you could easily create a true full circle with two segments. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54323852/1136211.

Answer (score 0):

Without second M (move) command:

```
Data="M0,5A5,5,0,1,0,10,5A5,5,0,1,0,0,5"
```

Radius: 5, Start (0,5)
Can omit the "z" at the end, and it is still a closed curve