# Is it possible to draw a circle (closed arc) using System.Windows.Shapes.Path?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to draw a circle (closed arc) using System.Windows.Shapes.Path?

I have tried this one:

```
<Path Stroke="LightGray" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M 0 5 A 10 10 360 1 0 0 5 Z"/>
```

but if i set the same start and end point (close the arc), then the circle will not be drawn.

So i have to trick:

```
<Path Stroke="LightGray" StrokeThickness="1" Data="M 0 5 A 10 10 360 1 0 0 4.9999 Z"/>
```

such a way i can get what i want, but the arc is not closed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not want to draw a segment, but a closed polygon. So it is not a duplicate

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate, but an [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10687055/1997232) uses [`A`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx#Anchor_3) draw command to draw circle.

Comment: I use A draw command, but it does not functioning. So you offere solution in  "duplicate" to draw to arcs 180° and 180°?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea from sinatra -> heinzi [WPF: is it possible to render a circle using GeometryDrawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165553/wpf-is-it-possible-to-render-a-circle-using-geometrydrawing) : to draw a two halfs of a circle with draw arc command.