# Circle in path geometry

Tags: c#, wpf

Please help me make a circle with a thickness of 2.
I was able to draw a filled circle (code below). How do I make it unfilled with a thickness of 2?

```
M 0,0 A 180,180 180 1 1 1,1 Z
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create a full circle with path markup because start and end point would be identical. You can only draw at least two circle segments, e.g. two semi-circles:

```
<Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2"
      Data="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 1 1 200,100 A 100,100 0 1 1 0,100"/>
```

You may perhaps better use an EllipseGeometry:

```
<Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2">
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100"/>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: Found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10687055/1997232) with just one `A`. Not sure how it works, is it done by [Z](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax#the-close-command)?

Comment: @Sinatr Besides that it's identical to what OP has posted here, it is not a full circle. There is a small gap that is closed by a straight line by the `Z` command. A full circle would have identical start and end point and would hence be undefined.

Comment: @Clemens I'm not comfortable using EllipseGeometry. Only if I can create it from C# code and then somehow convert it to path geometry (may be myEllipseGeometry.ToString()??). As I understand it can't be done?


I understood correctly that there is no way to specify StrokeThickness inside path geometry?

Comment: @AlexanderAnanev Not sure what you're asking. If you don't want to use an EllipseGeometry, use the path markup with two semicircles. The stroke thickness can only be set on the Path element. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Clemens Two half-rings will solve my problem, too, I think. Can you help me implement them? That would be great!

Comment: @Clemens ohh.. I'm a little distracted today. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have attached two images; one is the actual control image (radio button), and a graphic explanation of the Path/Data.

```
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Width="24"
                                Height="24"
                                CornerRadius="10"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource Light5Brush}"
                                Background="White" 
                                Margin="0"
                                BorderThickness="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                                      Width="18"
                                      Height="18"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                                      StrokeThickness="3"
                                      Fill="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"
                                      Stroke="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"
                                      Data="M 9,2 A 7,7 180 1 1 9 16 A 7,7 180 1 1 9 2 Z">
                                </Path>
```

[image: Hope it is self explanatory enough]